# Is this algebraic manipulation on this integral justifiable?

Tags: integration

I am new to integral but is this algebraic manipulation possible?

WHEREIN
$$\int \frac{dx}{1+cos(x)} \ $$

is equal to

$$\int \frac{dx}{1^2+(\sqrt{cos(x)})^2} \ $$

ASSUMING if it is equal, can I use arctan to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If you substitute $u=\cos x$, you also have to change $dx$ accordingly

Comment: Forgive me if I don't get it easily, can you expound it further sir?

Comment: See answer below of [B Goddard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/362009/b-goddard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and $$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$ the so called Weierstrass substituion.

Answer (score 0):

First, sometimes $\cos x$ is negative, so taking the square root might be a problem.

Second, supposing that you're going to integrate over a region where $\cos x$ is non-negative, when you substitute $u = \cos x$ you get $du = -\sin x \; dx.$
so your new integrand looks like

$$\frac{-du/\sin x}{(1+u^2)} = \frac{-du/\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}{(1+u^2) }= \frac{-du/\sqrt{1-u^2}}{(1+u^2)}$$

so I don't think you're any better off.

Third:  here's my suggestion.  Multiply the top and bottom of your integrand by $1-\cos x$ and see if you like that better.

Comment: Thank you for such enlightenment. So it can be deduced that such integral cannot be solved using arctan?

Comment: If you look at Graubner's answer and follow the Weierstrass substitution, you might try using arctan on the resulting integral.  I don't think it will come out very nice, though.